# Increase file ulimit for the asterisk daemon

Tags: linux, ulimit

How do i increase the file limit for the asterisk daemon on my ubuntu computer?  When I login as root and use the ulimit, it says unlimited already.  I can't login as asterisk because that user doesn't have shell access, it's just a daemon.

I can see in `/proc/<asterisk proc id>/limits` the current Max open files is 1024.  I want to double that.

I even went into /etc/security/limit.conf and added

```
asterisk soft nofile 2048
asterisk hard nofile 2048
@asterisk soft nofile 2048
@asterisk hard nofile 2048
```

THen I reboot server.  Still, the max open files is 1024.

What else can I do?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could always edit the `/etc/init.d/asterisk` file and prepend `ulimit -n 2048` to the top.

This is the same process that MySQL, Varnish and a few others use.

Comment: superb!!! it wored

Comment: @Ben Lessani. May i know where to paste 'ulimit -n 2048' in /etc/init.d/asterisk file. Inside start function or outside all methods?

Comment: At the top of the script, after the LSB data

Answer (score 3):

For Asterisk running under systemd (e.g. on Debian 9), you need to create a systemd override file:

```
mkdir /etc/systemd/system/asterisk.service.d/
```

Create `/etc/systemd/system/asterisk.service.d/override.conf` with the following contents:

```
[Service]
LimitNOFILE=100000
```

Reload the unit:

```
systemctl daemon-reload
```

Restart Asterisk:

```
systemctl restart astertisk
```

Check the limit:

```
cat /proc/<your asterisk PID>/limits | grep '^Max open files'
```

Answer (score 2):

I had this exact issue for anyone stumbling across this in the future (is it chrome?)

The system that I was having the issue on was Debian rather than Ubuntu, but hey, close enough.

I had to use the following in '/etc/security/limits.conf' to get it working, as specifying the user & group didn't work.

```
*               soft    nofile          10240
*               hard    nofile          10240
```

Logging in and out again applies this change.

Comment: What does logging in and out have to do with a specific running daemon? Do you mean "restart the service", or...?

Answer (score 2):

In Asterisk 11 (I've not checked others) this is set with the `maxfiles` directive in the `[general]` section of `asterisk.conf`. None of the other answers worked for me on Debian.

Answer (score 1):

It is better to edit the configurations in `/usr/sbin/safe_asterisk` instead on editing init.d script.

you can set many parameters (`PRIORITY`, `SYSMAXFILES`, `MAXFILES` ...). Uncomment SYSMAXFILES and MAXFILES; and increase their values.

Comment: Directly edit the executable?  Then the changes will be lost the next time the executable gets updated.  Configuration changes should go in config files.

Comment: That's no more of an executable than is /etc/rc.d/init.d/asterisk which was accepted, so, have an upvote. I find this method to be rather reliable.

Comment: @ItsMe; I Think you have the best answer, i have tried all other alternatives without success, but your solution is radical and clean. Thank's

Answer (score 1):

### Here is an easy way to increase ulimit value in asterisk.

Go to this file.
**/etc/asterisk/asterisk.conf**

```
[options]
internal_timing = no
maxfiles = 999999
```

**paste above line is `asterisk.conf` file then execute below commands.**

```
asterisk -rx "core restart now"
asterisk -rx "ulimit descriptors"
```

**Output**

```
Number of file descriptors (descriptors) is limited to 999999.
```